# Bring div to the front after 3d transition - css

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have a card which has information on the front & back, when the user hovers over the card it switches and shows the information on the back. It works in Firefox but not Chrome/Safari, in those browsers the text on the back is blocked although I tried using the z-index values. One thing to consider, the back of the card is allowed to overflow the container, that is on purpose. Could anyone point me to what needs to be included for the other two browsers?

The CSS is based on this post: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/flip/

Implementation: https://jsfiddle.net/af75qzqm/

Example Screenshots:

**Works in Firefox**

[image]

**Does not work in Chrome**

[image]

```css
#f1_container {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 23px;
  z-index: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  -moz-perspective: 1000;
  -ms-perspective: 1000;
  -o-perspective: 1000;
}

#f1_card {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #aaa;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  z-index: 0;
}

#f1_container:hover #f1_card {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  z-index: -10;
}

#f1_container:hover {
  z-index: 10;
}

#f1_container:hover .front {
  z-index: 0;
}

.face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  color: black;
}

.face.back {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: auto;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: white;
  z-index: 20;
}
```

```html
<div id="f1_container">
  <div id="f1_card">
    <div class="front face">
      Front
    </div>
    <div class="back face center">
      Back
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't try to get around the rules by wrapping your links as code, include the relevant code in the question itself, if the Fiddle link dies this question would lose all relevance.

Comment: That said, I tested in both Chrome and FF and I couldn't see any difference between the two, could you clarify what you mean by "blocked"?

Comment: This is not a bad question, but can be improved by including the minimum necessary code to reproduce the problem. Perhaps a screenshot with the problem and desired result would be a nice addition. @HiddenHobbes the white box is not stretched to the full height of the blue box content in webkit browsers.

Comment: @timo, I agree it isn't too bad a question, just needs the code and a bit more clarity. A screenshot would be good because both Firefox and Chrome exhibit the same behaviour (at least for me).

Comment: @HiddenHobbes I stand corrected, It is due to the lack of shadow in FF that I thought the white box scaled along with the blue box, it stays at the fixed width of 80px however, as expected.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes added the code here and example screenshots

Comment: @Mosh Feu: thanks for the edit!

Comment: @user263367 Thanks for updating the question, that's a lot clearer! The only problem is I'm unable to reproduce the issue shown in your screenshots using the code you have provided. Can you reproduce the issue yourself in the Stack Snippet or Fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the background color and border styles from #f1_card and added them to .face.front

https://jsfiddle.net/af75qzqm/2/

```
.face.front {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #aaa;
}
```